# use different but similar objects without branching

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Polymorphism, Code reusibility, OOP, C# question.  I would like to create a method like:

```
private void ManyLinesOfCode(DataContext mycontext)
```

but I wouldn't be able to send it my actual datacontexts because they are not of type DataContext and I haven't been able to do any casting that compiles.

```
var includeCustomersFlag = Request["includeCustomersFlag"];
if (includeCustomersFlag == "1")
   {
   var context = new TypeByRepGroupDataContext();
   var lines = context.TypeByRepGroups;
   .... many lines of code
   }
else if (includeCustomersFlag == "2")
   {
   var context = new TypeByRepGroupNoChainsDataContext();
   var lines = context.TypeByRepGroupsNoChains;
   .... many lines of code
   }
else
  {
   var context = new TypeByRepGroupChainsOnlyDataContext();
   var lines = context.TypeByRepGroupsChainsOnliess;
   .... many lines of code
   }
```

I have a workaround by using a single parameterized stored procedure in my datacontext instead of multiple datacontexts based on different views, but would prefer to have a c# solution to the bloated code above.

I am trying to work with Albin's solution.  I can compile this:

```
public interface IMyInterface 
{

    string arcxpostyy {get; set;}
    string arcxpostmm {get; set;}
    string CustArea {get; set;}
    string type {get; set;}
    System.Nullable<decimal> amt {get; set;}

}
partial class TypeByRepGroup : IMyInterface  { }
partial class TypeByRepGroupNoChain : IMyInterface { }
partial class TypeByRepGroupChainsOnly : IMyInterface { }
```

But... it doesn't get me anything as is.  I highly doubt I am making this interface right but I wanted to at least make an effort, and not sure how to use it in my code (the controller snippet in my question.)  No links on the internet to an actual implementation of this solution that I could find.  Can anybody fully spell out the solution?

I start a job as Senior Software Engineer in a couple weeks and would like to be able to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Abstract base class, interfaces ?

Comment: It looks like would want all of your context types to implement the same interface or inherit from the same base class. Is there some reason why you can't do that?

Comment: Interesting, I think that would be the classic way to solve the problem and I'll give it a shot when I have time.  These classes already inherit from System.Data.Linq.DataContext. Also the use of the anonymous type (var) I think adds to the problem.

Comment: @user985595, `var` is not an anonymous type, it is the type specifier for a type resolved at compile time. It **may** be an anonymous type, but in your case it is `Table<TypeRepGroup>` etc. The type can not change at runtime, it is not even remotely related to the VB6 `variant`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the type of the DataContexts that are the big problems here. It is that you use different entities on the different contexts.

Make sure `TypeByRepGroups`, `TypeByRepGroupsNoChains` and `TypeByRepGroupsChainsOnliess` implements a common interface. Create a partial class where you define that those classes implements the interface.

Comment: That sounds very interesting.  I'll give it a try when I get the chance and post my results.

Comment: Very tough going to figure out. First off, those 3 System.Data.Linq.Tables mentioned above are not allowed to implement an interface.  I get ; expected when I type : after them in the generated code.  public System.Data.Linq.Table<TypeByRepGroupChainsOnly> TypeByRepGroupChainsOnlies : (compiler gives warning right at the colon so I guess they are not classes at all) Then I play with this, play with that and am still not getting it done.  Back to bloated code for now.

Comment: I did try to inherit the ChainsOnlyDataContext and the NoChainsDataContext data contexts from the first one instead of from System.Data.Linq.DataContext and although that compiled, I still couldn't do what I want which is asign an instance of TypeByRepGroup to TypeByRepGroupNoChains if the flag indicated to use that data context.

Comment: Should be something like `partial class TypeByRepGroupChainsOnly : IMyInterface {}`. The empty brackets are required to create a valid class in c#.